# Break CE Cache for a Search Results Template when Any Entry Updated?

Tags: ce-cache

We're caching search results pages with CE Cache. I'm wondering if there's a way to bust the cache on these pages whenever any entry is updated? We have dozens of channels; I'd rather not specify all of the relevant tags in the control panel and/or template to use the normal cache busting process (e.g. add "search" as a tag to all of the channels when configuring them, or adding all of the different tags to the search results template).

Is there a way to quickly grab the date of the most recently updated entry and use that as part of the `id` parameter in the opening `exp:ce_cache:it` tag, or something? Perhaps some other trick I'm not thinking of?

**Edit** Perhaps the ability to specify `*` as a value for the `tags` parameter would be a cool feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply tag the Cache It tag in your search section with `search`, and then break on the `search` tag in the cache breaking settings for "Any Channel". That way, any time an entry changes (from any channel), your search results will be cleared.

Comment: Oh... didn't realize there was an "Any Channel" option in there. That'll do it!